# A number c in R is a cluster point of a subset A of R if and only if there exists a sequence An in A such that lim(an) = c for all n in N.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

This is also referred to as Thm. 4.1.2 in Bartle and Sherbet's intro to real analysis text. I am having a hard time fundamentally understanding what the sequence's role is in this proof, or why the sequence is even necessary to begin with. How would one formulate the sequence, and what is the purpose of choosing a sequence within the domain in the first place? Why does this sequence's convergence to a point tell us that it is a cluster point?

Comment: What is your definition of a cluster point?

Comment: Are you sure it says $\lim(a_n)=c$ for all $n$ in $N$? I'd expect simply $\lim(a_n)=c$.

Comment: Yes, I believe it means for all terms in the series when it says n in N. For the definition of a cluster point, there was the formal definition that as x approaches c, the absolute value is less than an arbitrary delta greater than zero.